# Sed Insert a newline before match

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to insert a string in multiple text files at a random line number. before adding the string in the text files i want to add a newline.

For example, a text file has 4 paragraphs.

```
paragraph 1

paragraph 2

paragraph 3

paragraph 4
```

I want the output to be

```
paragraph 1

STRING

paragraph 2

paragraph 3

paragraph 4
```

My code is working fine, but its not adding the empty newline before the string.

```
$ for i in *.txt; do sed -i "$(shuf -n 1 -e 2 4 6)i \n\rSTRING \n\r" $i ; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` command is actually `i\`, from the GNU manual:

```
'i\'
'TEXT'
     insert TEXT before a line.
```

So the backslash before the `n` is "eaten" by the `i` command. Add an extra backslash and it should work.